# Lightning: Get child records in Javascript

Tags: lightning

I have list of custom + child records (SOQL with inner select). I passed this list to array attribute in Lightning component. I can iterate through child records using aura:iteration in my component but I can't get this array in javascript 'for' loop using relationship. Any ideas?

As an example if we have list of accounts with contacts I want to get contacts using Account.Contacts in for loop of accounts.

Comment: seems like someone else did that with [opp.OpenActivities](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89121/auraiteration-iterate-through-child-objects) see the last comment. try to console.log your parent object, and see where it is hiding it's children records

Comment: I'm getting 'undefined' in console log. That is the reason why I asked this question actually ;)

Comment: So even your account (or equivalent) is undefined? if so, please post your component code so it's easier to find the error.

Comment: @Basti seems like I can't get them after sort function. That is how I use it:
`accontsArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(a.CreatedDate) - new Date(b.CreatedDate);
});`